# Calling javascript function removes text box validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using required validation on `TextBox1`.

The issue is when i call java-script function using `btnSave` it removes the validation.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1"  required=""  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSave" onclientclick="gotop()" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click1" />
```

java-script

```
<script>
    function gotop() {
        $(this).click(function () {
            $(window.opera ? 'html' : 'html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 'slow');
        });
    };
</script>
```

Comment: is `btnSave` calling `OnClick` on the server? causing a post/page refresh?

Comment: yes it causing a post-back

Comment: Which Validation you are talking about?

Comment: required field validation